# CodeIgniter current_url doesn't show query strings

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-string, uri

Hi I'm trying to store my current url in a session variable.

My app uses query strings like www.domain.com/add?url=http://www.google.com

but current_url() returns 'ww.domain.com/add'. The url without the query strings.

I've checked the helper file and current_url seems to just append the uri segments to the site_url set in the config.

```
    function current_url()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    return $CI->config->site_url($CI->uri->uri_string());
}
```

anyone know how I can grab the query strings to append them, or even just grab the whole url.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Create a MY_url_helper:

```
function current_url()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $url = $CI->config->site_url($CI->uri->uri_string());
    return $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ? $url.'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : $url;
}
```

Comment: That was awesome, it really helped me solve a problem. Thank you!

Comment: You can also name this function like `current_full_url()` to have the native function also available.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think CodeIgniter has any helpers for this. Just use PHP's native support for this:

Echo the full URL:

```
echo base_url().ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
```

Only the query strings:

```
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Comment: this method will only work if you have the project in your domain root, otherwise the project's folder will appear twice with this method.