# Codeigniter uri_string not returning the full path

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri, pathinfo

So being locate at this url (as an example) : `http://localhost/codeigniter-app/en/results?search_query=data`

`uri_string` doesn't return the needed path

```
["uri_string"]=>
  string(10) "en/results"
```

and the expected:

```
["uri_string"]=>
  string(10) "en/results?search_query=data"
```

Some of my `config.php`

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = false;
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

The problem is found when using http://codeigniter.com/wiki/CodeIgniter_2.1_internationalization_i18n library

Comment: Could you say what result you are expecting?

Comment: ops sorry, thought it was obvious... check the edit

Comment: Try adding [L,QSA] to the line in htaccess which contains index.php

Comment: @BenSwinburne to which line exactly? https://gist.github.com/d11be61ebca9bc49daab I've tried this one `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1` but no effect

Comment: One of your rewrite rules will have an [L] after it. Add in QSA

Comment: @BenSwinburne, adding QSA it has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended adding this in `application/core/MY_Lang.php` where I needed to get the correct path:

```
if(preg_match('/results/', $this->uri))
{
    $this->uri = $this->uri.'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
```

bellow: `$this->uri = $URI->uri_string();`

Answer (score 1):

You've got querystrings turned off - last time I used CI (back on 1.7.x), it ignored them. Try turning them on:

`$config['enable_query_strings'] = true;`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll have to use [`$this->input->get()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) to access the query string which, based on your example, would produce:

```
array(1) { ["search_query"]=> string(4) "data" }
```

Also, it's worth including this [from the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html):

> Please note: If you are using query strings you will have to build your own URLs, rather than utilizing the URL helpers (and other helpers that generate URLs, like some of the form helpers) as these are designed to work with segment based URLs.

Comment: the thing is that I don't need to get the `$_GET` data, but the url so I use it to change the language parameter.

Comment: @w0rldart: I understand, but as I mentioned, I think the only way to get the query string is with `$this->input->get()`. I think you'll have to use that in conjunction with `uri_string` to build the "complete" URL.

Comment: I kinda need `uri_string` to work because the url structure isn't always the same

Comment: @w0rldart: I understand your dilemma, but `uri_string` simply does not contain query string data. To get the query string, you'll have to use `$this->input->get()` or perhaps `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and build the full URL yourself. [Please see the accepted answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4160377/30433) for advice on creating a helper function to do that.