# CodeIgniter: current_url shows question mark

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

Say my page is on:

`http://localhost/app1/profile/index/123/`

The result of current_url() is this:

`http://localhost/app1/?profile/index/123`

There is a `?` that shouldn't be there. The question mark seems to be caused by the following config setting:

`$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;`

I need query strings enabled in my application. Any ideas what I need to do?

**EDIT 1:**

Also, in the case when the URL does have a query string, I need current_url to also return that. I'm hoping Phil Sturgeon's solution here [CodeIgniter current_url doesn't show query strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160377/codeigniter-current-url-doesnt-show-query-strings) will help me.

I'm using CI 2.1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, `$config['enable_query_strings']` is sort of a "legacy" setting in Codeigniter from back when there was no support `$_GET` (really, none).

> http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
>
> #### Enabling Query Strings
>
> In some cases you might prefer to use query strings URLs:
> `index.php?c=products&m=view&id=345`

`c` === Your controller name
`m` === Your method name

The rest is the method arguments. It's a very misleading description, and there's no mention of the other setting or query strings at all in the rest of the URL docs. I've never heard of anyone actually using this. CI comes with `$config['allow_get_array']= TRUE;` by default, which is what you want.

You can modify the `current_url()` function for query string support, just create `application/helpers/MY_url_helper.php` and use this:

```
function current_url($query_string = FALSE)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $current_url = $CI->config->site_url($CI->uri->uri_string());
    
    // BEGIN MODIFICATION
    if ($query_string === TRUE)
    {
        // Use your preferred method of fetching the query string
        $current_url .= '?'.http_build_query($_GET);
    }
    // END MODIFICATION

    return $current_url;
}
```

Then call it like `current_url(TRUE)` to include the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use: `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;`

Use this instead: `$config['allow_get_array']= TRUE;`

`enable_query_strings` is not what you think and is not used much.

To build your own query strings, use one of these two:

```
$query_string = http_build_query($this->input->get());
$query_string = $this->input->server('QUERY_STRING');
```

along with this:

```
$lastseg_with_query = $lastseg.'?'.$query_string;
```

Please consult this SO Q&A for more information: [URI Segment with Question Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464940/uri-segment-with-question-mark/10465002#10465002)

Comment: it's the same as `$current_url` in the answer by @WesleyMurch above. Does his answer not make sense to you? It is a more clear description of what you want.