# Code igniter URL?

Tags: codeigniter, url

URL Helper in CI is so bad thing, i dont know what to do :(

I have called

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

And on view i have called

```
echo current_url();
```

I got something like this ??

```
http://www.example.com/?druga
```

The real url is

**http://www.example.com/druga.html**

I think CI is not doing proper way, is there any help?

Comment: Only way to do this is $data->page = base_url().uri_string().".html";

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter: current\_url shows question mark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476042/codeigniter-current-url-shows-question-mark)

Comment: If the url really was what you say, with `.html`, then codeitniter's php would not execute. My guess is that you have an .htaccess file that is changing it.